# How SUM of COUNT() in this instance

Tags: mysql, count, grouping

What I am doing now: I have the `COUNT` of every user sorted by their `User_ID`, and each of those `User_ID`s are sorted into their `Age_groups`.

**What I'd like to do/my question**: How do I sort the `Age_group` with the highest count of `User_ID`s in that group? It will allow me to see the most popular `age_group`.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
SELECT user_id AS User_ID, ROUND(FLOOR(DATEDIFF (NOW(), user_dob))/365, 0) AS Age, COUNT(reservations.reserv_id) as Reservations_Per_User_ID,
case
    when ROUND(FLOOR(DATEDIFF (NOW(), user_dob))/365, 0) > 30 then "30+"
    when ROUND(FLOOR(DATEDIFF (NOW(), user_dob))/365, 0) between 25 and 30 then "25-30"
    when ROUND(FLOOR(DATEDIFF (NOW(), user_dob))/365, 0) between 20 and 25 then "20-25"
    when ROUND(FLOOR(DATEDIFF (NOW(), user_dob))/365, 0) < 20 then "18-20"
    else "error"
end as age_groups
FROM users, reservations
WHERE users.user_id = reservations.Users_user_id
GROUP BY user_id
```

And here's the output:

```
ID  Age Count Age_group
1   22  6   20-25
2   30  10  25-30
3   24  18  20-25
4   28  14  25-30
5   26  13  25-30
6   18  12  18-20
7   26  10  25-30
8   28  10  25-30
9   26  8   25-30
10  26  6   25-30
```

Relevant data:

**For the `Users` Table and some sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_country` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_phone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_dob` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Users`
--

LOCK TABLES `Users` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Users` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `Users` VALUES (1,'Lucio','Vazquez','canada','lvazquez0@infoseek.co.jp','128-852-1295','1997-09-12'),(2,'Claude','Barck','us','cbarck1@addthis.com','391-281-1575','1989-10-19') ...;
```

**For the `reservations` table and some sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE `Reservations` (
  `reserv_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reserv_date` date NOT NULL,
  `reserv_numppl` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Location_Loc_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Users_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Promoters_promoter_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Shows_show_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Packages_package_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reserv_id`,`Location_Loc_id`,`Users_user_id`),
  KEY `fk_Reservations_Location1_idx` (`Location_Loc_id`),
  KEY `fk_Reservations_Promoters1_idx` (`Promoters_promoter_id`),
  KEY `fk_Reservations_Users1_idx` (`Users_user_id`),
  KEY `fk_Reservations_Shows1_idx` (`Shows_show_id`),
  KEY `fk_Reservations_Packages1_idx` (`Packages_package_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Reservations_Location1` FOREIGN KEY (`Location_Loc_id`) REFERENCES `location` (`Loc_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Reservations_Users1` FOREIGN KEY (`Users_user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`)

INSERT INTO `Reservations` VALUES (1001,'2018-07-07','2',640,69,NULL,NULL,NULL),(1002,'2018-03-04','9',605,29,'111',NULL,'702'),(1003,'2017-11-19','3',641,41,NULL,NULL,NULL),(1004,'2018-08-16','4',606,96,'103',NULL,'703'),(1005,'2017-12-05','4',642,51,NULL,NULL,NULL),(1006,'2017-04-25','5',627,75,'120',NULL,NULL), etc...
```

Thank you

Comment: A (wrong) query and the (wrong) output it produces is not enough information to fully understand what you have and what you want, i.e. give you a good answer. [Edit] the question and include the `CREATE TABLE` statements of all the relevant tables, sample data for them as `INSERT INTO` statements and the result you desire with that sample data.

Comment: That query is not counting users (unless there is a unique key on `reservations.Users_user_id`). Also, implicit "comma" join notation has generally considered archaic poor form for over a decade, as it makes for harder to maintain queries; you might want to look into explicit JOIN notation.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question.. but a more accurate and simpler way to get the age is `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, user_dob, NOW())`.

Comment: @stickybit I added the relevant `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERTS`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thank you